# Removing <br> from Handlebars Template

Tags: javascript, templates, replace, handlebars.js, helper

I have a template that is populated from a database driven by a CMS. A CMS where the people that enter in the data don't really know HTML, they just say they do.  So they'll enter in a series of break tags (incorrectly, mind you) instead of just wrapping their content in a paragraph.

I am then importing all of that into a neat little template, and using that data to populate data-labels to display on buttons, and other stuff.

I've seen a few Handlebars Helpers that say they do a find and replace, but I have no idea how to write the syntax IN my template to compile it with grunt without it flagging errors.  Here's the helper I wanted to use:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('replace', function( find, replace, options) {
    var string = options.fn(this);
    return string.replace( find, replace );
});
```

Now this looks pretty straight forward, but there's no documentation on how to actually toss the stash in your template other than {{#replace}}

The parameter I'm trying to look through is {{caption}} and I'm looking for ever instance of '
' and replace it with ''.

When I write the stash like this: {{#replace '`<br>`', ' ', caption}}, but then I get a parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you would want to use a block helper in this situation. I think the following regular helper would do:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('replace', function (find, replace, context) {
    return context.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
});
```

Note that I am using a RegExp so that we can replace *all* instances of the `find` text.

You would then use this helper within your template in the following way:

```
{{replace '<br>' ' ' caption}}
```

Comment: ...now I've getting a "Uncaught Error: MIssing helper: 'replace'", and I just put it into the template before the Handlebar blocks

Comment: What does "put it into the template" mean?

Comment: I have blocks of Javascript at the top of the template to set all the functions, and block of javascript at the bottom that run on document ready. in the actual body of the template is the handlebars markup.

Comment: I am not quite sure what your issue is, but maybe an example will help: https://jsfiddle.net/e130xqau

Comment: maybe what the issue is that we are using handlebars.min.js - I see your example is using full uncompressed handlebars.  I will see if that resolves the situation.

Comment: well, still no dice running handlebars.js. I have developed a JFIDDLE so you can see my template, but most of the data is database driven, and I cannot connect to my database from JFIDDLE. https://jsfiddle.net/murphy1976/ne8y8w5q/